# python appending a list to a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have following tuple:

```
vertices = ([0,0],[0,0],[0,0]);
```

And on each loop I want to append the following list:

```
[x, y]
```

How should I approach it?

Comment: FYI you don't need to end your lines with a semi-colon in python.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, could you give an example of what you want? How do you want them appending? etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't append a `list` to a `tuple` because tuples are ["immutable"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) (they can't be changed). It is however easy to append a *tuple* to a *list*:

```
vertices = [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
for x in range(10):
    vertices.append((x, y))
```

You can add tuples together to create a *new*, longer tuple, but that strongly goes against the purpose of tuples, and will slow down as the number of elements gets larger. Using a list in this case is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a tuple. You'll either need to replace the tuple with a new one containing the additional vertex, or change it to a list. A list is simply a modifiable tuple.

```
vertices = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

for ...:
    vertices.append([x, y])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two tuples:

```
>>> vertices = ([0,0],[0,0],[0,0])
>>> lst = [10, 20]
>>> vertices = vertices + tuple([lst])
>>> vertices
([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [10, 20])
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a list, as mentioned above. But if you really need a tuple, you can create a new tuple by concatenating tuples:

```
vertices = ([0,0],[0,0],[0,0])
for x in (1, 2):
    for y in (3, 4):
        vertices += ([x,y],)
```

Alternatively, and for more efficiency, use a list while you're building the tuple and convert it at the end:

```
vertices = ([0,0],[0,0],[0,0])
#...
vlist = list(vertices)
for x in (1, 2):
    for y in (3, 4):
        vlist.append([x, y])
vertices = tuple(vlist)
```

At the end of either one, `vertices` is:

```
([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you, but if you want to append x,y to each vertex you can do something like :

```
vertices = ([0,0],[0,0],[0,0])

for v in vertices:
    v[0] += x
    v[1] += y
```